# Ubuntu 16.04: Xorg cpu usage and usb hub

Tags: 16.04, usb, xorg, cpu

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo Thinkpad. I observe high Xorg CPU usage whenever I connect my USB hub on a particular USB port. That doesn't happen when the hub is shifted to a different USB port. It may make sense if the cpu usage is coming from some USB driver, but of all, it comes from Xorg, which I understand controls the graphics behavior. Can someone let me know why it happens and if there are any solutions other than using the second USB port for the hub?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Ubuntu 20.04 which amazingly enough was caused by using a custom version of .Xmodmap.

Further reference:

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=306352